# .NET MAUI Unable to Navigate Between Pages

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, maui-windows

I want to use page navigation for my .NET MAUI project. Although I do the same as the instructor did in the Udemy Course, it gives me the following errors. I can't figure it out, can you help me?

I am getting these four errors:

1. The target "UpdateDesignTimeXaml" does not exist in the project.
2. The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context
3. The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
4. The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

   [image: Click for the error image]

I created several pages in my .NET MAUI project. I want to try to navigate between these pages. But I am getting the errors I mentioned.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing the code that you're having trouble with. **Never** provide code and error messages as images, please. They should **always** be in text form.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, accidentally create Xamarin.Forms Pages in a .NET MAUI project? That already happened to me, too, and resulted in errors like those.

Comment: MAUI and Xamarin, are not the same thing. No matter how some people try to present it to you. They cannot be used together. And the very nature of achieving the "multiplatform" feature is different. I am saying all this, judging by your random tags of your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to create a new page in the Maui project, please select .Net Maui. Such as:

[image]

The default maui page's name is such as **NewPage1** and the xamarin form's default name is such as **Page1**. You added a xamarin forms page not a maui page in your project.

Comment: I had previously selected C# Items --> .NET MAUI ContentPage (XAML) as the file path. 
But now I have selected C# Items --> Web --> .NET MAUI ContentPage (XAML) as the file path and the error is fixed. Thank you, sir.